# How to disable qInfo() output

Tags: qt, debugging, qdebug

I have follwing code snippet to run. In which I want to see result of qDebug() but I dont want see result of qInfo(). I want to configure it on basis, sowetimes I need those qInfo() output and sometimes not.

```
    qInfo()<<"Info print";
    qDebug()<<"Debug print";
```

In above code, I want only 'Debug print' should print. but can't comment qInfo() line.

Answer (score 2):

As it described on the [Qt debug documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInfo), you have to compile with `QT_NO_INFO_OUTPUT` to disable it.

```cpp
# your .pro file
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS QT_NO_INFO_OUTPUT
```

---

You can also use define for other macro:

> ***`qDebug()`***: disable with `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT`
>   ***`qInfo()`***: disable with `QT_NO_INFO_OUTPUT`
>   ***`qWarning()`***: disable with `QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT`
>   ***`qCritical()`***: enable with `QT_FATAL_CRITICALS`

Answer (score 1):

You can choose at runtime which category enable (even for custom category) with `QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules`

From Qt Docs, exampe with custom category:

```
QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules(QStringLiteral("driver.usb.debug=true"));
```

For your case:

```
QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules(QStringLiteral("*.info=false"));
```

take care of using `"*.info=true"` because enable everything, even for profiling category usually disablet